# How to create azure data factory pipeline on local machine for dev debug?

Tags: debugging, azure-pipelines, local, azure-data-factory

I create service which uses few ADF pipelines, which will be responsible for processing of large amount of big files.

The main purpose is not to create azure services like database, azure storage account and pipelines on local developer account with 50Euro credit. The biggest drawback of such solution is size of processed file. Such big files could burn credit and blue CK such account.

Structure of a project looks like:
**web-ui - API server - azure data factory with pipelines (unit used for processing and calculation files)**. In order to develop and debug such project everything should be configurable on local machine. Data factory with pipelines will use database information in order to process and create calculations on files

I looked for different approaches to deploy such projects with ADF pipelines, but there is no general solution for such structure. **Is it possible to simulate and create local instance of pipeline on developer's machine?**

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Only solution which I can imagine is creation of local flow which not use whole pipeline but particular azure functions. Azure functions can be executed locally. We have got switch between local debug and other environments.

Comment: Too bad... thanks for the follow-up